# I can´t create tables in my database postgresql with springboot

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying that springboot creates a table in my PostgreSQL database, spring connects correctly to the database but doesn't create any table.

[image: pgadmin display]

Hibernate configuration

application.yaml

```
spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

This is the entity that I need to put into the database

User.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name= "users")
public class User {
    //iduser
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    private String idUser;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String rol;
    private String language;

    public User(){

    }
}
```

PostgressApplication.Java

```
package com.sample.postgres;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.sample")
public class PostgresApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PostgresApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

pom.xml

I have a lot of dependencies in my proyect how can you see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>postgres</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--  JPA y Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[My estructure code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmWs.png)

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: I have the version 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Add `@EntityScan("com.sample.modelo")` at the top of `PostgresApplication` class:

```
package com.sample.postgres;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.sample")
@EntityScan("com.sample.modelo")
public class PostgresApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PostgresApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

More information:

Your configuration seems fine to me. Make sure your entity is scanned. What I mean is that you may have configured your project in a way that your entity class are not read. Here is the minimum configuration you need to have:

1. Use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Have your `application.properties` in `src/main/resources`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mysecretpassword

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

1. Create your entity (you already have this)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name= "users")
public class User {
    //iduser
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy="uuid2")
    private String idUser;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String rol;
    private String language;

    public User(){

    }
}
```

4. Have your `@SpringBootApplication` class

```
package your.package;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackTest.class);
    }

}
```

And this is where it is more than important ! If your entity class `User` is not in a sub-package of `your.package`, then you need to add a custom annotation to your `@SpringBootApplication` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("my.other.package")
public class MainApp {

}
```

### More on Hibernate configuration

When configuring an application with JPA, without Spring-boot, you need to provide the location of your entity classes (and also a lot more other information).

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
// many codes here
configuration.addPackage("my.package.for.entities");
```

This tells hibernate to scan specific packages to look for your entities.

With spring-boot, you don't have to write the entire configuration classes. But if your entites (and this is your case) is in a different packages than your `@SpringBootApplication`, then you need to specify the packages to scan with the annotation `@EntityScan("my.package.for.entities")`. Indeed, this is this annotation that is interpreted by the class `JpaBaseConfiguration` to look up for your entities.

The annotation `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "my.package")` is here to look up for your spring beans, and not your entities.

If everything's fine, you should see this in your log:

> Hibernate: drop table if exists users cascade
>   Hibernate: create table users (id_user varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), language varchar(255), last_name varchar(255), password varchar(255), rol varchar(255), primary key (id_user))

Let me know.

Comment: I don´t have the log that you sent, I add to my code the postgresapplication.java for you to see it

Comment: Add to your `PostgressApplication` the `@EntityScan("com.sample.modelo")` annotation

Comment: I'm trying to use the design patron MVC, so com.sample.modelo is where I'm thinking to put all my entities

Comment: Was that!!! Thank you so much for your help, if you add that to your answer I can put it as the correct answer

Comment: well, I did, but I'll put it more obvious

Answer (score 0):

The **create-drop** strategy will delete after your application shuts down. Try **create** instead.

Next to that: looking at your property file:

```
spring:

datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

its indented in a way, it looks like it is not finding your jpa config, since it is nested underneath datasource.

try:

```
spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
      properties:
        hibernate:
          temp:
            use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
          jdbc:
            lob:
              non_contextual_creation: true
```

Comment: Sorry, was a problem of my copypaste, but I have the code like you sent me

Comment: This doesn´t fix my problem

Comment: You also have the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency? And can you try with: jpa:hibernate:ddl-auto: create

Comment: but I don´t turn off spring before I revised the database, yeah I have that dependency

Comment: you have:show-sql: true
what does it output when you start Spring?

Comment: What is the output? tI should mention something about creating the table..

Comment: The text of the console, you mean?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean :)

Comment: I have a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null but I don´t know If is something related because is caused by org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() that is something of images.

Comment: Can I sent you all the output somehow?

Comment: Update your question with the output please :)

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. I can´t upload all the code because of this

Comment: Yes, but I mean I have so much code in the output that it doesn't let me upload it

Comment: try: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

Comment: But where I put this? In the application.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

try to use only create instead of create-drop

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
      properties:
        hibernate:
          temp:
            use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
          jdbc:
            lob:
              non_contextual_creation: true
```